# Python – next function – list comprehension

Tags: python-3.x, iterator, list-comprehension

I am trying to understand why code written in a compact style works and the “same code-ish” in a more verbose style does not work.

This code yields the correct answer:

```
which_days = [5, 12, 19, 26]
buy_day = next((i for i in which_days if i in range(13, 20)), None)
print(buy_day)
>>> 19 <- correct answer
```

This code does yields a pair of brackets:

```
which_days = [5, 12, 19, 26]
buy_day = []
for i in which_days:
    if i in range((13, 20), None):
        next(which_days)
print(buy_day)
>>>[] <- This is a pair of brackets
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the long form of the correct code:

```
which_days = [5, 12, 19, 26]
def _tmp_variable():
    for i in which_days:
        if i in range(13, 20):
            yield i
buy_day = next(_tmp_variable(), None)
del _tmp_variable
```

The incorrect code does not work because it is doing something entirely different (not to mention illegal; you can't call `next()` on a list in Python 3).

Here's a different long form, which builds the entire list eagerly instead of lazily yielding one element at a time:

```
which_days = [5, 12, 19, 26]
_tmp_variable = []
for i in which_days:
    if i in range(13, 20):
        _tmp_variable.append(i)
buy_day = _tmp_variable[0] if _tmp_variable else None
del _tmp_variable
```

As you can see, this is wasteful because it builds up an entire list and then only uses the first element.  Fortunately, the short version of your code does not do this.

Comment: Thanks Kevin - question about your comment. You said that "you cant call next() on a list in Python3". I thought that is what line 2, of the first set of (working) code is doing - can you tell me what that line is actually doing?

Comment: @chadbyoung: In that case, you are calling `next()` on a generator expression, not a list.  If you changed the parentheses to square brackets (turning it into a list comprehension), you would get a `TypeError`.

Comment: @Kevin unlike the original code the OP has posted, your first example will raise a `StopIteration` instead of `None` where no match is found, and your second example will raise an `IndexError`... also not quite sure what's going on with the `_names` and `del`s...

Comment: @Jon: Fixed.  The underscores are intended to show that those variables don't really exist (in the sense that they do not appear, even briefly, in the local/global variable scope and are inaccessible from Python), and the `del` is meant to reinforce this in an intuitive and obvious fashion.